# Installation of Rubygems fails on Ruby 2.0.0 Install on OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install rubygems but get the following error:

```
'$ rvm install ruby
 ......... 
Installing rubygems-2.1.11 for ruby-2.0.0-p353............
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global GEM_HOME=/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -d /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/setup.rb',
please read /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/log/1386179561_ruby-2.0.0-p353/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
 ........  
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p353    
pristine..............
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.0.0-p353 /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/scripts/gemsets pristine',
```

please read /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/log/1386183855_ruby-2.0.0-p353/gemset.pristine-ruby-2.0.0-p353.log

.rvm/log/1386179561_ruby-2.0.0-p353/rubygems.install.log states:

```
[2013-12-04 17:59:26] /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
current path: /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11
command(6): env GEM_PATH=/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global GEM_HOME=/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -d /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/setup.rb
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1087 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1096 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:332:in `load_file'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
from setup.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

Command Line Developer Tools are installed. Ruby gets successfully installed. . .

```
$ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]

$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

But gems are all wrong:

```
 $ gem -v
 /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in `load_file'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:192:in `initialize'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Tried this:

```
$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.

rvm get stable
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/Vasenka/.bashrc /Users/Vasenka/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/Vasenka/.bash_profile /Users/Vasenka/.zlogin.
Installing rvm gem in 1 gemsets /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in `load_file'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:192:in `initialize'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Check this article - [Using Rbenv to Manage Multiple Versions of Ruby](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/15/using-rbenv-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-ruby/)

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with libyaml or an issue related to xcode after upgraded to Mavericks:

```
$ xcode-select --install # if you upgraded to Mavericks
$ brew update # if using homebrew
$ rvm get head # to get lastest rvm
$ rvm pkg install libyaml
$ rvm pkg install readline
$ rvm reinstall all --force
```

Other possibility is some YAML parse error on your `~/.gemrc`

If none of that works try [rvm GUI ruby manager](http://unfiniti.com/software/mac/jewelrybox) (free) for OSX or [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org) which will set RVM for you.

Comment: my `~/.gemrc` has the following: `install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-rigem: --no-document
gem: --no-document`

Comment: `$ brew install libyaml
Warning: libyaml-0.1.4 already installed`

Comment: The GUI does not help with the broken gemsets.

Comment: try `xcode-select --install` that will install xcode command tools that might have been removed by an OSX update. Then retry the `rvm get head` instead of `rvm get stable`

Answer (score 0):

could try with this `rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --verify-downloads 1`

Comment: same result: `Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353:/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global GEM_HOME=/Users/Vasenka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -d /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/setup.rb'
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p353 pristine Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.0.0-p353 /Users/Vasenka/.rvm/scripts/gemsets pristine'`